# useEffect for chained fetch calls

Tags: reactjs, use-effect

I'm chaining two fetch calls to retrieve data. The first call gets a token and then second call uses that token to get the data. Here's an example:

```
fetch("[GET THE TOKEN]")
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then(token => {
    fetch("[GET DATA]?token="+token)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        return data;
      });
  })
```

The issue is that I need to make lots of different calls sometimes within the same component and writing that chained call over and over again can get tedious and if I need to make changes it's a lot of code to edit.

I came up with a functional solution but I haven't stress tested it yet. I'm still a react noob so feedback would be helpful

*context.jsx*

```
const [token,setToken] = useState('')
const fetchToken = async () => {
    fetch("[GET THE TOKEN]")
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      setToken(data);
    });  
}
```

*component.jsx*

```
const {token, fetchToken } = useContext(context)

//fetch data function
const [initFetch,setInitFetch] = useState(false);
const fetchData = () => {
 fetch("[GET DATA]?token="+token)
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((data) => {
    return data;
  });
}

//action that inits fetch data
const submitForm = () => {
  setInitFetch(true)
}

//useEffect that will trigger the function on initFetch and token const changing values
useEffect(() => {
  if (token && initFetch === true) {
    fetchData();
  }
},[token,initFetch]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I see that you want to call this `fetch function` when you submit the form, Therefore, you should not do that with an `useEffect`, simply because you don't need to.

Use the `useCallback` hook and create an async function inside of it. Call it almost wherever you want.

See:

```
const MyComponent = () => {

  const {token, fetchToken } = useContext(context)
  const [initFetch, setInitFetch] = useState(false);

  const fetchData = useCallback(async () => {
    const response1 = await fetch(`[GET DATA]?token=${token}`);
    const jsonFromResponse1 = await response1.json();

    return jsonFromResponse1;
  }, [token])

  const randomFunc = async () => {
    const data = await fetchData()
  }

  return (
    <button onClick={fetchData}>Button</button>
  )
}
```

The dependency array of `useCallback` is crucial, if you don't insert it, when the token changes, the hook will never update the function with its new value.

You can continue to use `then`. But I strongly recommend you to try await/async. It will make your code way easier and readable.

Comment: ah, useCallback seems like a helpful call. Do you know any good tutorials? MDN and react docs all read like the plumbus bit from rick and morty

Answer (score 0):

What I get from you question, that you are looking for some way to not repeat your fetch calls.
If that's so, I believe you can go with a custom hook that you can call every time you need.
something like that

```
const useFetchFn=(arg)=>{
  fetch(arg)
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((data) => {
    return data;
  });
}
```

Then in your component

```
const [token,setToken] = useState('')
const fetchToken =useFetchFn("[GET THE TOKEN]")
```

Comment: That's a bit cleaner but I still need the token to make the other fetches.

Comment: fetchToken shall store the value returned, in case of [GET THE TOKEN] I suppose it's the token itself. Then you should estimate your project if it need global state management as context api or redux, then you will call your reducer and store the token, or simply local state using useState, I was just demonstrating a solution for repetition of code and fetch calls

Comment: yeah, i already have the fetch token in the context, but the fetch calls for the data need to happen synchronously upon getting a fresh token